# How can I correctly parse a JSON array in android?

Tags: android, arrays, json

I'm trying to parse some information but I get some errors. This is part of my code:

```
public static ArrayList<Advertiser> negociosCiudad(String ciudad){
    ArrayList<Advertiser> result = new ArrayList<Advertiser>();
    JSONParser jp = new JSONParser();
    JSONArray jArray = jp.getJSONFromUrl(URL + "searchByCity/" + ciudad);
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

            Advertiser a = new Advertiser();
            JSONObject o = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            a.setDireccion(o.getString(TAG_ADDRESS));
            a.setId(o.getString(TAG_ADVERTISER_ID));
            a.setCiudad(o.getString(TAG_CITY));
        ...
        }
}
```

This is what I'm receiving:

```
["Hello","Good Bye","Errors","Everywhere","Help", ...]
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
org.json.JSONException: Value Hello at 0 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

I haven't figured out how to do this correctly, but I believe it's something simple. I realized that I'm not using JSON arrays, but I don't know what to do.

I'll be editing this post with the things I'm trying to do to fix it.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT

I had a mistake and put a different response, let me get the real one since ["Hello","Good Bye","Errors","Everywhere","Help", ...] is from another query –

Comment: what you did receive is a `JSONArray`, and contains `String`s

Comment: That json doesn't make sense for what you are tying to do. Are you sure your json is valid? From your code your actually want something that looks like `{"TAG_ADDRESS":"1234 Some Rd", "TAG_ADVERTISER_ID":"546", "TAG_CITY":"City"}`

Comment: I had a mistake and put a different response, let me get the real one since ["Hello","Good Bye","Errors","Everywhere","Help", ...] is from another query

Answer (score 1):

You need an object which holds your array, like this:

```
{
 "arrayOfIntegers": [
   1,
   2,
   3,
   4,
   5
 ]
}
```

Anyway, personally, if you aren't work with big Jsons, and you dont look for maximum performence you could simply use [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

You can fetch it from maven at "com.google.code.gson".